# Какая хеш функция у /etc/shadow?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, хеширование

Какой хеш использует Ubuntu в `/etc/shadow`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

вообще в файле `/etc/shadow` может встретиться хэш, сделанный любым из [поддерживаемых алгоритмов](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man5/crypt.5.html).

по умолчанию для новых паролей используется значение `ENCRYPT_METHOD` из файла `/etc/login.defs`. см. вывод в своей системе. пример:

```
$ grep ^ENCRYPT_METHOD /etc/login.defs
ENCRYPT_METHOD SHA512
```

но, конечно, использованный алгоритм можно определить и по внешнему виду хэша: начинается хэш с указания этого самого алгоритма. к примеру:

- `$5$` — это sha256crypt
- `$6$` — это sha512crypt

и т.д. и т.п. // полный список смотрите по приведённой выше ссылке.

---

доп. чтение: [`$ man login.defs`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man5/login.defs.5.html)